# LPCXpresso 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, ide, execute-command

I'm trying to install LPCXpresso IDE 8 on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit but I receive an error:

```
No protocol specified
invalid command name "bind"
    while executing
"::unknown bind Text <Tab>"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $next $args"
    (procedure "::obj::Unknown" line 3)
    invoked from within
"bind Text <Tab>"
    (procedure "::InstallJammer::InitializeGui" line 19)
    invoked from within
"::InstallJammer::InitializeGui "
    (procedure "::InstallJammer::InitInstall" line 68)
    invoked from within
"::InstallJammer::InitInstall"
    (file "/installkitvfs/main.tcl" line 38978)
```

I've installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libxtst6:i386
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxtst6:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 \
         libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 \
     libncurses5:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-1.0:i386 libusb-0.1:i386 \
     gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libnss3-1d:i386
```

and

```
cd /lib/i386-linux-gnu
sudo ln -sf libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

But nothing seems working.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo ./Installer_LPCXpresso_8.0.0_526_Linux-x86 --mode console
```

Resolved my problem.
See also https://www.lpcware.com/content/forum/lpcxpresso-8-ubuntu-1404-64-bit